# Recursive Algorithm similar to Golden Ratio

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

> Given a finite sequence of positive integers *[a<sub>0</sub>,a<sub>1</sub>,...,a<sub>n</sub>]* (of 
>       length *n+1*), define a new finite sequence *[b<sub>0</sub>,b<sub>1</sub>,...,b<sub>n</sub>]* by the 
>       recursive formula
>
> b<sub>n</sub> = a<sub>n</sub> + 1/b<sub>n-1</sub>
>
> For example:
>
> b<sub>0</sub> = a<sub>0</sub>
>         b<sub>1</sub> = a<sub>1</sub> + 1/b<sub>0</sub> = a<sub>1</sub> + 1/a<sub>0</sub>
>         b<sub>2</sub> = a<sub>2</sub> + 1/b<sub>1</sub> = a<sub>2</sub> + 1/(a<sub>1</sub> + 1/a<sub>0</sub>)
>         b<sub>3</sub> = a<sub>3</sub> + 1/b<sub>2</sub> = a<sub>3</sub> + 1/(a<sub>2</sub> + 1/(a<sub>1</sub> + 1/a<sub>0</sub>))
>               .
>               .
>               .
>         b<sub>n</sub> = a<sub>n</sub> + 1/b<sub>n-1</sub> = a<sub>n</sub> + 1/(...  + 1/a<sub>0</sub>)
>
> Write a function called `sequence_to_fraction` which takes one input 
>       parameter `a` (a Python list of positive integers *[a<sub>0</sub>,a<sub>1</sub>,...,a<sub>n</sub>]* ) and 
>       returns the last number *b<sub>n</sub>* in the sequence defined above
>
> b<sub>n</sub> = a<sub>n</sub> + 1/(a<sub>n-1</sub> + 1/( ... + 1/a<sub>0</sub>))

So far this is the code I have right now. And I don't know what more to add to complete this. As of now, I have an index out of range error. What do I do next?

```
def sequence_to_fraction(a):

    b = [0]
    b[0] = a[0]

    for i in range(0,len(a)+1):
        b[i] = a[i] + 1/b[i-1]
        b.append(b[i])
        b[i-1] = b[i]

    return b[len(b)+1]
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what that first chunk of code is written it.  It certainly is not Python.

Comment: It's LaTeX on Jupyter platform @UtahJarhead

Comment: Thank you so much!! @DanielRoseman

Comment: Unfortunately StackOverflow does not support LaTeX. I replaced the LaTeX code with markdown code that has its limitations. I hope it comes close enough.

Comment: Thank you, do you have any suggestions for my code? @trincot

Comment: I am actually surprised that you don't have a division in your code, while the requirements clearly give expressions having a division...

Answer (score 0):

For a recursive solution, see how b<sub>n</sub> uses b<sub>n-1</sub> (when n > 0). The base case is when n = 0 and where the recursion should stop. This latter case happens when the input list has only one element:

```
def sequence_to_fraction(a):
    if len(a) == 1:
        return a[0]
    return a[-1] + 1/sequence_to_fraction(a[:-1])
```

Note how `a[:-1]` is passed in the recurring call: this is a copy of the list without the last element; so it is one element shorter.

Comment: What does a[-1] and a[:-1] do?

Comment: `a[-1]` is like `a[len(a)-1]`; it is the last value in the list. `a[:-1]` is a copy of the whole list up until the last element, which is excluded from the copy.

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You already handled the special case where i=0, so the loop should start at 1.

The loop should iterate across all elements in a after 0, so it should count up to the last valid index in a. That is NOT len(a)+1.

You attempt to assign it to b[i] which does not exist yet. Instead just append the number you calculated (or store it in a temporary variable for readability and to make debugging easier).

You also get the last item in b incorrectly in your return statement. Again, len(b)+1 is not correct.

(code intentionally not posted, as this is homework, but this should be enough to get you there)

Comment: I'm just addressing the actual bugs. You might also consider a design change of keeping the last value of b, instead of storing a list that you don't need.

Comment: For correctness, you really need to hand-compute some test cases and have your code automatically check them. (unit tests)